# html: navbar background-color doesn't change

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Why this navbar background, won't change?

I need to put this navbar in a black background, but even with the `!important` argument I cannot get it working.

The css class is even at the bottom of my `custom.css` file.

What could be wrong?

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="

        Welcome to the Cushion Store

">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/custom.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css"
          integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="container-fluid bg-light nav-bar-fixed-top my_top_navbar_div">


<!--- GALLITO NAVBAR --->

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top navbar-bg">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault"
            aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">


        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Stickers <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Etiquetas</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Magnetos</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pines</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pines</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Empaques</a>
            </li>
        </ul>


        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
            </li>


                <li class="nav-item active">

                </li>


            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Registro</a>
            </li>
        </ul>


    </div>
</nav>
```

**custom.css:**

```
    body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

/* === NavBar === */
.nav-item {
    letter-spacing: .2em;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}


.dropdown-item {

}


/* == Footer ==== */

.my_footer {
    background-color: #5a6268;
}

.my_footer p {
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
}


/* == Category Page == */

.my_row_class {
    padding-top: 15px;
}

.my_row_class .mx-auto p {

    color: #000;
    font-size: 12px;
}


.my_row_class .mx-auto p a {

    color: #000;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.my_image {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.my_title {
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: .2em;
}

.my_image_padding {
    padding-top: 16px;
}

.my_bottom_margin {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.card-body h4 {
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: .2em;
}

/*=== Product Page ==*/

.my_prod_row_class {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.my_prod_row_class .mx-auto p {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 12px;
}


.my_prod_row_class .mx-auto p a {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
}


.my_prod_title {
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: .2em;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.my_prod_text {
    padding-right: 20px;
}

/* === Pay With Card === */

.stripe-button-el {
    width: 100% !important;
    display: block !important;
    background-color: #868e96 !important;
    border: 0px !important;
    background-image: none !important;
}

.stripe-button-el span {
    display: block !important;
    position: relative !important;
}


.errorlist li {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}


.my_custom_div {
    margin-bottom: 20px !important;
}

.my_top_navbar_div {
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 50px;
}

.my_custom_menu {

    text-align: right !important;
}

.my_custom_menu ul li {
    list-style: none;
    color: black;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: .2em;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    display: inline;
}


.my_custom_menu ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    list-style: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: .2em;
    font-size: 12px;
}





/* BOTONES JUMBOTRON */



.btn-azul {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #5ba4e6;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.25);
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: 1.2;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  -ms-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  -o-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(255,255,255,.09) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,.09) 100%);
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  padding: 22px 30px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border:none;
}

.btn-azul:focus {
    outline:none;
}


.btn-azul:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #7ab6eb;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.25);
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: 1.2;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  -ms-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  -o-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(255,255,255,.09) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,.09) 100%);
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  padding: 22px 30px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border:none;
}


.btn-naranja {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #ffa31a;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.25);
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: 1.2;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  -ms-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  -o-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(255,255,250,.09) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,.09) 100%);
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  padding: 22px 30px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border:none;
}

button.btn-naranja:focus {
    outline:none;
}




button.btn-naranja:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #ffad33;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.25);
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: 1.2;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  -ms-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  -o-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(255,255,255,.09) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,.09) 100%);
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  padding: 22px 30px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border:none;
}






/* ==================== */

.btn-xlarge {
    padding: 18px 28px;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: normal;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
       -moz-border-radius: 8px;
            border-radius: 8px;
    }



nav.navbar {padding: 0 1rem;}

li.nav-item:hover {
  background-color: saddlebrown;
}


/*=== NAVBAR === */


.navbar-bg {
    background-color: black !important;
}
```

**UPDATE 1:**

I think that it has to do with mi css file that is saved in "cache"?

When I comment all my css clases the page looks the same. But when I remove/add back the classes directly in the HTML, through the console, I see changes in the page.

I've refreshed my page with `CTRL + F5` but no effect takes place. I should mention that this is a web page developed with Django in PyCharm 2018.

Comment: please add custom.css files. because works on codepen: https://codepen.io/dgknca/pen/BvBJbK?editors=1100

Comment: @DogukanCavus I've edited and added all the `custom.css` file

Comment: still works: https://codepen.io/dgknca/pen/BvBJbK?editors=1100 Try this code: `.navbar-bg {background-color: black !important;z-index:999;}`

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark fixed-top">
```

and remove `.navbar-bg` class from your css file.

Comment: But, it works removing the class navbar-bg that sets a manual background-color. What if I need to use a particular color?

Comment: bg-dark is a color class build directly in Bootstrap, there's no need to create your own class to ad a color...unless you don't need a particular color.

Comment: If you need a particular color remove bg-dark and do your own class

Comment: yeah I know, but that is not black enough for me. how can I set my own bg color in css?

Comment: That's  what I did with `.navbar-bg`. this doesn't solve the problem :(

Comment: Just try remaning your custom class to some not so similar that the classes that Bootstrap defines. Example: `custom-navbar-bg: { background-color: coral;}` and then try using it. If you want to analyze why is not working, use the inspector tool.

Comment: add ".nav-bg {background-color: #000000;}" in your css and in the navbar and remove bg-dark.

Answer (score 1):

Just exactly the same problem with me. Here is the answer. Look at your code here:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/custom.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css"
```

The order of your css stylesheet has been ordered that the custom.css is lower level than the bootstrap css style sheet. So that when the code runs, it just simply overrides your stylesheet by bootstrap style if available (in this case, because bootstrap has background Color already so it will automatically replace your background Color)

Solution:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css"
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/custom.css">
```

Just put the custom css to the bottom of these links of everything will be fixed!

*Note: And don't forget the hard fresh (shift + reload) to make the changes!

Answer (score 0):

Well, your code works (just tested it).

The reason it does not work for you *could be* that **your browser saved a cached version of your webpage**.

So in your browser, try a "hard reload" to remove any potential cached version and reload the page.

To do that in Chrome: open developer tools (hit F12) and then right click on the refresh icon of the browser. Select "empty cache and hard reload", and see if it works for you.

Comment: I though the same, I even did CTRL + F5 and restarted the PC but nothing.